# getting deeply nested JSON decoded into Swift

Tags: json, swift, decodable

2 Questions

1. How do I get to the nested "close" value of a specifi item? Do I do this by struct within a struct within a struct to replicate the coding structure.
2. What do I do with the number "1594647000" do I use enum with CodingKey?

> ```
> {
>     "meta": {
>         "currency": "USD",
>         "symbol": "AAPL",
>         "exchangeName": "NMS",
>         "instrumentType": "EQUITY",
>         "firstTradeDate": 345479400,
>         "regularMarketTime": 1597176001,
>         "gmtoffset": -14400,
>         "timezone": "EDT",
>         "exchangeTimezoneName": "America/New_York",
>         "regularMarketPrice": 437.5,
>         "chartPreviousClose": 383.68000000000000682121026329696178436279296875,
>         "previousClose": 450.91000000000002501110429875552654266357421875,
>         "scale": 3,
>         "priceHint": 2,
>         "dataGranularity": "15m",
>         "range": ""
>     },
>     "items": {
>         "1594647000": {
>             "date": "13-07-2020",
>             "open": 388.720000000000027284841053187847137451171875,
>             "high": 394.18999999999999772626324556767940521240234375,
>             "low": 388.3500000000000227373675443232059478759765625,
>             "close": 392.76999999999998181010596454143524169921875
>         }  
> }
> ```

Comment: If you have `struct DayRecap: Codable { let date: String (could use a DateFormatter here, but that's for another time), let close: Double, etc. }` decode `let items: [String: DayRecap]` should be enough, since in fact `1594647000` is a unixtimestamp in String, representing the date "13-07-2020"

Comment: You could use something like the following site in order to get an idea of how you would represent it in swift: https://app.quicktype.io/

Answer (score 0):

Does this make sense?
Depend on your need, you may want to keep the `items` as a dictionary or you may want to convert it into an array.

```
let jsonString = """
{
    "items": {
        "1594647000": {
            "date": "13-07-2020",
            "open": 388.720000000000027284841053187847137451171875,
            "high": 394.18999999999999772626324556767940521240234375,
            "low": 388.3500000000000227373675443232059478759765625,
            "close": 392.76999999999998181010596454143524169921875
        }
    }
}
"""

struct Item: Decodable {
  let open: Double
  let close: Double
}

struct ItemsList: Decodable {
  let items: [Item]

  private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
      case items
  }

  init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

    let dict = try container.decode([String: Item].self, forKey: .items)
    items = dict.map { $0.value }
  }
}

let itemsList = try JSONDecoder().decode(ItemsList.self, from: jsonString.data(using: .utf8)!)
```